# how add action button to payload onesignal json apns file

Tags: ios, react-native, notifications, onesignal, payload

I try to add action button in notification onesignal react-native ios.So i used apns file for test in simulator, the notification coming with dragging file but action button does not appear even i made a long press can anyone give me the correct aps format json and thinks for help
this my payload apns file for test:

```
{
    "Simulator Target Bundle": "******",
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "title": "Push Notification",
            "subtitle": "Test Push Notifications",
            "body": "Testing Push Notifications on iOS Simulator",
            "actionButtons":[
                       {
                       "id":"test",
                       "text":"test"
                        }
                           ]
             
        }
    },
    "custom": {
        "i": "notificationId as UUID",
        "a": {"deeplinkKey": "{\"deeplinkDetailKey\":\"deeplinkDetailValue\"}", "launchURL": "example://collection/myCollectionId/type/1"}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- OneSignal does not support action buttons in iOS push notifications. You can achieve a similar effect by including a category in your payload. Here's an example of modifying your payload to add a category.

  ```
  {
   "Simulator Target Bundle": "******",
   "aps": {
       "alert": {
           "title": "Push Notification",
           "subtitle": "Test Push Notifications",
           "body": "Testing Push Notifications on iOS Simulator"
       },
       "category": "testCategory"
   },
   "custom": {
       "i": "notificationId as UUID",
       "a": {"deeplinkKey": "{\"deeplinkDetailKey\":\"deeplinkDetailValue\"}", "launchURL": "example://collection/myCollectionId/type/1"}
   }
  }
  ```
- In your app's code, you can handle the category in the didReceiveRemoteNotification method of your UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

  ```
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
   if response.notification.request.content.categoryIdentifier == "testCategory" {
       // Handle the category action here
   }
   completionHandler()
  }
  ```
- User Notifications
  Push user-facing notifications to the user’s device from a server, or generate them locally from your app : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications

Comment: Note that used react-native not full native ios to handle actions button